# Change the default folder in a Synology NAS

Tags: ssh, nas

I have an Synology DS212+, and when I log with root putty via ssh, I always enter in the folder /root.

How can I change that? I want to enter by default in /volume1. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go edit /etc/passwd and change the home directory that root has. Change

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
```

to

```
root:x:0:0:root:/volume1:/bin/ash
```

Answer (score 1):

In DSM 7, this is how to fix and achieve the desired operation...

1. Go to CONTROL PANEL > FILE SERVICES > FTP
2. Then scroll down and select ADVANCED SETTINGS.
3. You will be presented with the Advanced Settings dialogue, now check the "Change User Root Directories" and click the "Select User" button.
4. Select your SFTP group or user and the directory you want to be the default directory when this SFTP user logs in.
5. Save the settings and apply them and you should now be presented in the folder you chose for that user or group when logging into the SFTP server.